# How to configure a sub domain for my Office 365/SharePoint online subscription?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I have an Office 365 subscription (ramXXXXX.sharepoint.com).
My public facing website is at www.mydomain-name.com, which is managed by another Hosting provider (not on office 365).

While I want my SharePoint online sites to be on intranet.mydomain-name.com, I do not want my public facing site to be effected.

Note, I do not want email, lync and other services to be configured. I just want the SharePoint sites on my sub domain.

If this is possible, I am looking for some pointers on how/where to start with this configuration. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An Office365 SharePoint-URL always looks like this: https://tenantname.sharepoint.com. You cannot change this URL - so choose your tenant-name wisely! There is no direct way to let your users use http://subdomain.company.com.

Some ideas for workarounds (with pro and con!):

- Create a CNAME in your DNS called "subdomain.company.com". I tried this some time ago and it didn't work. Just got some HTTP Code 200 without any useful content.
- Host a small Website and configure it to listen to http://subdomain.company.com. Use a [HTTP Redirect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302) to move your users to SharePoint-Online. This only works if your users type "http://subdomain.company.com" in their browsers. Does not work if users have browser-bookmarks, connected lists to outlook (contacts, tasks, ..) or shortcuts (open-in-explorer, ..). You could improve this simple solution with [URL-Rewritng](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite).

Answer (score 2):

You can do redirect from mydomain-name.com to ram.sharepoint.com. You cannot rename the SP site and you cannot change your private site collection domain.

Please check out this user voice entry:

https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/13217277-enable-renaming-the-site-collection-urls

Also read the second answer [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/813d8102-6f29-496e-88b1-b709a568ec84/changing-sharepoint-online-urls-customvanity-domains?forum=onlineservicessharepoint) from Matt - Bonafide Software:

> 1. You cannot change the url for a private site collection. If the alternate access mapping feature was exposed, then it could be done.(...)
> 2. You cannot change the address of the My site collection. This is because  you cannot create a site collection using the "My site host
>      template".  In addition, even if you could find a way to create a
>      custom site collection based on the My site host template, you could
>      not change set the my site host location to this new url, because the
>      textbox is greyed out and cannot be edited.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/tenant-rename
It is now possible with quite a few caveats.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.